# tail a .txt file that is open by a different application

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, text, tkinter

Im trying to use tools like [tailer.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tailer/) to follow a log that is constantly being updated by a different application. The output goes to a Text widget in a GUI for monitoring. If I point it to a test file I can add text, save, and the widget updates with the new information. If I point it to the log file that is being updated by the other application it watches the file but I never get output from it.

I do not know what kind of lock the other application has on the file but it definitely has a hold of the file. I can not copy the file or edit/save anything to the file because it is in use.

I've tried several different tools and processes I've found online but none are able to watch the file while it is in use. I AM able to query specified lines from the file though over and over without a problem. Its just watching the file does not detect changes.

Maybe I can query the file and only return lines that were not in the last query? I think this would be a constant .open()/.close() on the file but if its my only option i'll try to work with it. Any recommendations for getting around this?

=========================================================================
7/8/2016

Testing watchdog:

```
import watchdog
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
path = "C:\\test\\"

class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print(test)

    def on_created(self, event):
        pass


observer = watchdog.observers.Observer()
handler = MyHandler('*/file.log')
observer.schedule(handler, path)
observer.start()
```

I would expect this to print test every time something happens to the file.log. Comparing to the giant class examples I see on other pages I think maybe im missing something to specify  the type of event to watch for?

Comment: In [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), set the lower pane to show the process handles. Add columns to the handle view for the handle type, name, access mask, and share flags. Click on the process that's writing the log, and sort its handles by type. Look for the log file handle. If it exists, what are the values for its access mask and share flags? It may not be listed if the application doesn't keep the file open.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and is it giving any errors specifically? That might help to debug this issue.

Comment: Not listed. In Process monitor I can see the process open,write,query, and close the log. So it doesn't keep it open. Any ideas?

Comment: In Process Monitor, check the properties of the `CreateFile` event to see what the desired access and share mode are when the file is opened. With the file already opened in Python, does the application's `CreateFile` call succeed or fail?

Comment: elder4222 I dont know what I can try. I was hoping someone would know if it was possible to watch a log that is locked down like this one is. If its not possible to watch it then does anyone have examples on how to open, read, close a file and only pull new information when it is seen?

Comment: Eryksun- desired access is "generic read/write" and the sharemode is "None". I'll have to monitor it later tonight or tomorrow to see if the createfile fails when python has it open.

Comment: The application probably doesn't retry the call with sharing allowed. That means you can't keep the file open in Python. You need to monitor the directory for changes, either by directly using a Windows API such as [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465) via ctypes or PyWin32, or by using a package that does this for you.

Comment: I'll look into ways to monitor the file for changes and then query the file. If anyone has recommendations feel free to list.

Comment: A user generally isn't notified of replies unless it's on her or his own question or answer. Otherwise you need to manually notify someone by addressing the comment to his or her username, prefixed by "@", e.g. @sidnical. As you start typing, a box should appear that contains the closest matching user name in the current context, which you can click on to automatically complete the rest of the name.

Comment: As to suggestions, try [watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog). On Windows it uses the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` API. You can subclass the `watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler` and override its `on_modified` method to implement an action when files that match the pattern are modified in the watched directory. The pattern uses shell wildcards such as `'*/app.log'` and it has to match the `src_path` of the event. Note that the latter is a fully qualified path, which is I started the pattern with `'*/'` to match a filename.

Comment: @eryksun I found that the process that writes to the log starts showing sharing violation in process monitor when my application starts reading the file. Does this mean my program is "blocking" the file and keeping anything from editing it? This works with other files that get a slow trickle of updates. The log im having issues with is constantly being updated... maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Unlike Unix, Windows requires declaring how read, write, and delete access can be shared when opening a file. Sharing access isn't the same as file locking, which is a separate mechanism that's more precise (e.g. a range of bytes in a file can be locked). The application is trying to open the log file exclusively, so you can't leave it open in Python. That's why I suggested watching the directory using watchdog. When you get a notice that the file has been modified, loop trying to open it until you get access, and then read it from the previous position (i.e. the old file size).

Comment: @eryksun I looked at some of the watchdog documentation and its really confusing to me. I got watchdog installed but never figured out how to use it correctly. Im newish to coding and its alot to wrap my head around. Any examples you can provide?

Comment: Get an observer, e.g. `observer = watchdog.observers.Observer()`. Get a handler, e.g. `handler = MyHandler('*/the_log_filename')`. Schedule the handler to watch a given path, e.g. `observer.schedule(handler, path)`. Then start it, e.g. `observer.start()`. Your handler should subclass an existing handler such as `watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler`, and override the methods that you need, such as the `on_modified` method.

Comment: @eryksun I added an example of what I created above. When I run this it just finishes with exit code 0. Am I missing something to specify the type of event to watch for?

Comment: The handler's methods are called on a worker thread. Your main thread has to provide the actual application interface. Notice in the documentation's simple example that it uses a while loop that requires the user to break via Ctrl+C. When the loop is broken, it calls the observer's `stop` and `join` methods to exit cleanly. Also, you have to do the work for the event in the methods `on_modified` and `on_created`. You can't just `pass`; that's ignoring the event.

Comment: Im still not understanding the process. I'll just have to find a different way of doing it because I cant find an example that makes sense to me. Thanks for your help @eryksun. I think im just too new to wrap my head around the options in watchdog.